# Neither mod_substitute nor mod_sed are replacing anything in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

I am running Apache  2.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 and I have both `mod_sed` and `mod_substitute` installed and enabled via `a2enmod`. I am trying to get basic output replacement but not getting any results. I have this replacement running on Windows (both Apache 2.4 and Apache 2.2) with no problems but I can't get any combination to work on Ubuntu. Here is what I am using:

```
<Location />
        AddOutputFilter Sed html
        AddOutputFilter SUBSTITUTE html
        AddOutputFilter Sed text/html
        AddOutputFilter SUBSTITUTE text/html
        AddOutputFilterByType Sed text/html
        AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
        OutputSed "s/harvest/HRRVST/g"
        Substitute "s/harvest/HRRVST/"
</Location>
```

I have included all of the different output filters I have tried both separately and all at once. I have tried this block in the main `apache2.conf` as well as in a `VirtualHost` block. I have tried both `Directory` and `Location` blocks in both places. I have confirmed that the file is being processed and that I am accessing the correct server in the browser.

Is there something I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 8):

If you need both modules `mod_deflate` and `mod_substitute` you can add

```
SetOutputFilter SUBSTITUTE;DEFLATE
```

to your `<Location>...</Location>` and the filters will be used in this order.

Comment: ¡muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3):

The answer turns out to be that `mod_deflate` was enabled and was causing the filters not to work.